# How do I create an empty custom table in Wix?

Tags: wix, dtf, custom-action

How do I get Wix to include a CustomTable with no rows in the final MSI? If I simply define the table like this

```
<CustomTable Id="MyTable">
  <Column Id="Id" Type="string" Category="Identifier" PrimaryKey="yes"/>
  <Column Id="Root" Type="string"/>
  <Column Id="Key" Type="string"/>
  <Column Id="Name" Type="string"/>
</CustomTable>
```

Wix omits it from the final output.

My DTF CustomAction is expecting it to be there, so that it can add rows to it during execution.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks to a comment in this [blog post](http://blog.torresdal.net/CommentView,guid,FE27427F-FF4F-4056-BC50-C98E23227C6D.aspx) (which, by the way, has a very useful example of a DTF Custom Action) I found the Wix [EnsureTable](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wix_xsd_ensuretable.htm) element, which makes sure a table appears in the output, even if it is empty.

So to make my example work, I need to do this:

```
<CustomTable Id="MyTable">
  <Column Id="Id" Type="string" Category="Identifier" PrimaryKey="yes"/>
  <Column Id="Root" Type="string"/>
  <Column Id="Key" Type="string"/>
  <Column Id="Name" Type="string"/>
</CustomTable>

<EnsureTable Id="MyTable"/>
```